# Pegar dados da planilha excel e inserir no banco de dados SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server, microsoft-excel

Quero saber se tem como pegar os registros de uma planilha e jogar para uma tabela do SQL-SERVER, existe essa possibilidade ?

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/121767/importar-excel-para-sql-server-c

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsql-server%5D+excel

Comment: Bom dia. Então qual a versão do seu sql server, uso aqui o sql server 2012 e tem um programa nela que já faz esta importação automática, desde que a tabela esteja criada certinha no seu banco de dados, o nome do programa e Import and Export Data que se encontra dentro da pasta Microsoft sql server.

Comment: sua pergunta já foi respondida aqui https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/30413/5846

Comment: Onde fica esse programa, não consigo achar ele nem na pasta, uso o sql server 2012 também.

Comment: Este programa fica na maquina onde o sql server esta instalado

Comment: Usa o assistente do sql server o "IMPORT AND EXPORT DATA" para imputar sua planilha direto no banco de dados